# How do I use elements in Varien_Data_Form_Element_*?

Tags: system.xml, varien

In `system.xml` one can simply use elements like `text` and `select` and all the tutorials out there are using these two as examples. But how should I use other elements listed in `lib/Varien/Data/Form/Elements` folder?

For example there is a `Fieldset` and I noticed that it has `getLegend` and `getElements` methods but adding `<legend>Some Text</legend>` or `<elements><!-- Elements --></elements>` nodes did not work. How should I use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form::initFields is responsible for generating fields from system.xml.
It uses `frontend_type` to figure out which element to generate

```
$fieldType  = (string)$element->frontend_type ? (string)$element->frontend_type : 'text';
```

And generating code itself:

```
     $field = $fieldset->addField($id, $fieldType, array(
                'name'                  => $name,
                'label'                 => $label,
                'comment'               => $comment,
                'tooltip'               => $tooltip,
                'hint'                  => $hint,
                'value'                 => $data,
                'inherit'               => $inherit,
                'class'                 => $element->frontend_class . $sharedClass . $requiresClass,
                'field_config'          => $element,
                'scope'                 => $this->getScope(),
                'scope_id'              => $this->getScopeId(),
                'scope_label'           => $this->getScopeLabel($element),
                'can_use_default_value' => $this->canUseDefaultValue((int)$element->show_in_default),
                'can_use_website_value' => $this->canUseWebsiteValue((int)$element->show_in_website),
            ));
```

$fieldset is here type of `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset`.

So using system.xml you can create any elements of Varien_Data_Form_Element_*. But there is a limit for input parameterss from xml config.

Made a small investigation for possible parameters, so they are:

- frontend_model
- frontend_type
- label
- hint
- backend_model
- comment
- tooltip
- tooltip_block
- depends
- shared
- requires
- validate
- can_be_empty
- source_model
- if_module_enabled
- show_in_default
- show_in_website
- show_in_store
- config_path

All other  will be ignored.